# Cannot execute sudo apt-get update

Tags: updates, sudo

I am new to Ubuntu and when I execute

```
sudo apt-get update
```

I get the following errors and warnings

```
W: GPG error: http://ppa.launchpad.net quantal Release: The following
 signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not
 available: NO_PUBKEY 5A9A06AEF9CB8DB0 W: Failed to fetch
 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/quantal-security/Release.gpg 
 Something wicked happened resolving 'security.ubuntu.com:http' (-5 -
 No address associated with hostname)

 W: Failed to fetch
 http://extras.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/quantal/Release.gpg  Something
 wicked happened resolving 'extras.ubuntu.com:http' (-5 - No address
 associated with hostname)

 W: Failed to fetch
 http://packages.medibuntu.org/dists/quantal/Release.gpg  Something
 wicked happened resolving 'packages.medibuntu.org:http' (-5 - No
 address associated with hostname)

 E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old
 ones used instead.
```

Can anyone tell me what is wrong?

Answer (score 0):

For the error with signature:

```
sudo gpg --keyserver hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com:80 --recv-keys 5A9A06AEF9CB8DB0
sudo gpg --armor --export 5A9A06AEF9CB8DB0 | sudo apt-key add -
```

Then,
    sudo apt-get update
    sudo apt-get upgrade

The reason you need to do this is that you added a PPA to your sources.list without trusting the key it uses to sign packages.

Answer (score 0):

According to http://forums.linuxmint.com/viewtopic.php?f=90&t=147271 medibuntu team has called it quits.
just go into "Software Sources" > "Other software" and uncheck "http://packages.medibuntu.org/"